# How do I find all n values for which the equation $\phi (n) = 8$ holds?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, totient-function

I've heard all kinds of different ways to solve this problem, yet haven't been able to apply them specifically to the number 8 (Worked fine for 6 for example). I'd love to see a well-explained solution, is possible.
Thank you.

Comment: Since $\varphi(p^a)=p^{a-1}(p-1)$ we see that no odd prime can divide $n$ with exponent $>1$ and that any odd prime dividing $n$ must be one greater than a power of $2$.  Not hard to check all the cases.

Comment: In general one can compute the inverse of this function.

Comment: It helps the OP more, if you show how the inverse of this function can be computed. It is not totally trivial. The numbers {$15,16,20,24,30$} satisfy $\phi(n)=8$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/23955/589 for how hard it is in general.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* 
If $p^e$ divides $n$, then $\varphi(p^e)=p^{e-1}(p-1)$ divides $\varphi(n)$.
Therefore:

- $p=2$ and $e-1 \le 3$, or
- $p$ is odd and $e=1$ and $p-1$ divides $8$.

This limits the possible candidates for $p^e$. You then need to argue how these candidates can be combined to yield $\varphi(n)=8$.