# Solving equation involving Euler's totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Given $m\in\mathbb{N}$, is there a general way to solve the equation
\begin{equation}
\varphi(n)=m
\end{equation}
where $\varphi$ is the Euler's totient function? For example, I want to solve for all the $n$'s such that $\varphi(n)=4$. Is there any way to solve it that are also applicable to many (if not general) cases?

Comment: For related problems, see Ford's Theorem and Carmichael's Totient Conjecture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the equation $\phi(n) = k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23947/how-to-solve-the-equation-phin-k)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdot p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$, where $p_i$ are disntinct prime numbers.

Then, $\varphi(n)=p_1^{k_1-1}(p_1-1)p_2^{k_2-1}(p_2-1)\cdots p_r^{k_r-1}(p_r-1)=2^2=1\cdot 4=2\cdot 2$.

Now it is easy to conclude $r=1$, $p_1=2$, $k_1=3$ or $p_1-1=4$, $p_1=5$, $k_1=1$ (remain case $p_1-1=2=p_2-1$, isn't possible since $p_1\neq p_2$).

Solutions are $n=8$ and $n=5$.

Comment: What about $p_1 = 5$ and $k_1 = 1$?

Comment: @ dhk628 Thanks for observing that, I  added that solution.

Comment: Thanks. Can you briefly explain how you get the equation $\varphi(n)=p_1^{k_1-1}(p_1-1)\cdots p_r^{k_r-1}(p_r-1)$? Sorry I am new to this function and do not know too much about the property of this function.

Comment: The number of integers $t\leq p_i^{k_i}$ that are divisible by $p_i$ is $p_i^{k_i-1}$.  Thus the number of $t$ **not** divisible by $p_i$ (or in other words, coprime to $p_i^{k_i}$) is $p_i^{k_i}-p_i^{k_i-1}=p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)$

Comment: Solutions are $5$, $8$, $10$, $12$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the wiki

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Unsolved_problems

and look up "totient numbers".  There are many nontotient numbers.  The page as a whole is very informative.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I have actually looked up the page before, and I found that $n=5,8,10,12$ satisfy $\varphi(n)=4$, and it also seems that the larger the $n$, the larger the $\varphi(n)$, so it seems natural to conjecture that these four are the only $n$'s with $\varphi(n)=4$. However I have no any rigorous argument before the answer's given here.