# Find all $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $\phi(n)=4$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I know that there is a similar post, but I 'm trying a different proof.
I will write $P$  for the set of all positive prime numbers.

**Question:** If $\phi$ is Euler's Phi Function, we want to find all $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $\phi(n)=4$.

**Answer:** Let $n=p_1^{n_1}\dotsb p_k^{n_k}\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ be the factorisation of $n$ in to primes. Then
$$\phi(n)=p_1^{n_1-1} \dotsb p_k^{n_k-1}(p_1-1) \dotsb (p_k-1)=4.$$

So, for any $i \in \{1,2,\cdots,k\}$ we have $p_i-1|4$. Hence,
$$p_i-1\in\{1,2,4\} \iff p_i\in \{2,3,5\} \subset P.$$
Now, we can see the primes that $n$ contains: $n=2^{n_1}3^{n_2}5^{n_3}$, where  $n_1,n_2,n_3 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. So,

\begin{align*}
\phi(2^{n_1}3^{n_2}5^{n_3})=4 \iff \phi(2^{n_1})\phi(3^{n_2})\phi(5^{n_3})=4  \tag{$*$}
\end{align*}

The possible cases for $n_i$ are:

- $n_1=1,2,3\implies \phi(2)=1,\phi(2^2)=2, \phi(2^3)=4$ respectively
- $n_2=1 \implies \phi(3)=2$
- $n_3=1 \implies \phi(5)=4$

All the posible combinations for the relation $(*)$ are $\phi(5)$, $\phi(5)\phi(2)$, $\phi(3)\phi(2^2)$, $\phi(2^3)$. So, $$n \in \{5,10,12,8\}.$$

Is this completely right?

Thank you.

Comment: Look good to me.

Comment: Yes, its right! ( only a typo: n_2=n_3=1)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be completely correct to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we work similarly to find all  $n\in \mathbb{Z} ^+: \phi(n)=x$ for some $x>4$?

Comment: Yes, this technique is general, though the casework can be a difficult computation.

Comment: @Chris, for the general case, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23947/how-to-solve-the-equation-phin-k.

Comment: See also A Method for Solving $\Phi (x) =n$ 
L. L. Pennisi
The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. 64, No. 7 (Aug. - Sep., 1957), pp. 497-499 (3 pages)
Published By: Taylor & Francis, Ltd.
https://doi.org/10.2307/2308462
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2308462