# Find smallest $N_0$ such that $\phi(n)\geq 5 \; \forall n\geq N_0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

> Find smallest $N_0$ such that $\phi(n)\geq 5 \; \forall n\geq N_0$
>   where $\phi$ is Euler's Totient function

I can't think of a way to tackle this. Please help me

Comment: Note:  $\phi(12)=4$

Comment: I note that but how do I actually prove that there won't be any integer $k>12$ that will not dissatisfy the statement

Comment: Find all $n$ such that $\phi(n)=4$. then you are done. Have a look at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127998/find-all-positive-integers-n-such-that-phin-6?rq=1) for this.

Comment: @RossMillikan the inequality $\phi(n) \geq \sqrt n$ in that answer is false, at least for a few small numbers such as $n=2$ and $n=6$

Answer (score 1):

I claim $N_0=13$.  If $n$ is divisible by $2^4, 3^2, 5^2, $ or a prime $p\ge7$, then by the multiplicative property of the totient function $\phi(n)\ge6$.  So if $\phi(n)<6$, then $n=2^a3^b5^c$ with $0\le a\le3$ and $0\le b,c\le 1$.  There are $16$ numbers of this form; only $7$ of those are above $12$, and it can be checked that for those $7$ the totient function is $6$ or more.

On the other hand $\phi(12)=4$, so $N_0>12$.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, we can explicitly list all $n$ such that $\phi(n) = 1, 2, 3,$ or $4$.

Recall that we can compute $\phi$ using prime factorization: if $n = 2^{x_1} 3^{x_2} 5^{x_3} \ldots$, then
\begin{align*}
\phi(n)
&= \phi(2^{x_1}) \phi(3^{x_2}) \phi(5^{x_3}) \cdots
\end{align*}
The first term of the product $\phi(2^{x_1})$ is a power of $2$.
Next, $\phi(3^{x_2})$ is one of $1, 2, 6, 18, \ldots$, so if $\phi(n) = 1, 2, 3, \text{ or } 4$ then the only possibility is $2$.
Next, $\phi(5^{x_3})$ is one of $1, 4, 20, 100, \ldots$, so it can only be $1$ or $4$. $\phi(7^{x_4})$ and everything after that can only be $1$. So we have that
$$
\phi(n) = (1, 2, \text{ or } 4) \cdot (1 \text{ or } 2) \cdot (1 \text{ or } 4)
$$
And the only possibilities are in the table below:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\phi(n) = 1 & 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 & n = 1, 2 \\
\phi(n) = 2 & 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 & n = 3, 6 \\
            & 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 & n = 4 \\ 
\phi(n) = 3 &  - & - \\
\phi(n) = 4 & 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 4 & n = 5, 10 \\
            & 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 & n = 12 \\
            & 4 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 & n = 8
\end{array}
$$
We see that for all $n$ such that $\phi(n) = 1, 2, 3,$ or $4$, $n$ is at most $12$. So for $n \ge 13$, $\phi(n) \ge 5$.

Comment: also $\phi(n)=4$ when $n=10$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality in one of the linked answers is wrong. The first one below has equality at 2, the second one at 6, third at 30.

$$  \phi(n) \geq \sqrt{ \frac{n}{ 2} }.  $$

$$  \phi(n) \geq 2 \cdot   \left( \frac{n}{6} \right)^{2/3}.  $$

$$  \phi(n) \geq 8 \cdot   \left( \frac{n}{30} \right)^{7/8}.  $$

The first one says $N_0 = 50$ is good enough. Using a calculator for the roots, the second one says $N_0 = 24$ is good enough, while the third says $N_0 = 18$ is good enough. So, check up to 18.

see [Is the Euler phi function bounded below?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below/301856#301856)

I give a proof at the same question.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\phi(n)=4$ if and only if $n=5,8,10,12$, see below. Also $\phi(n)$ is never $3$ and $\phi(n)=2$ if and only if $n=3,4$. Hence we can conclude
that $\phi(n)\ge 5$ for all $n\ge 13$.

Reference:
[Find all $n \in \mathbb{Z^+} : \phi(n)=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080977/find-all-n-in-mathbbz-phin-4)