# Determine the solutions of $\varphi (n) = 30$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

Determine the solutions of $\varphi (n) = 30$.

I already understood that the possible solutions will be $31$ because it is prime and $62$ because it is double $31$, but I don't know how to justify that there is no more possible solution and prove that these two are the only possible ones.

Comment: Well, do you know how to relate $\varphi(n)$ to the prime factorization of $n$?

Comment: HINT: $30$ contains a factor of $5$. How can that arise? Either from $n$ containing a power of $5$, or from $n$ containing a prime factor which is $1$ greater than a multiple of $5$. See if you can use those facts to limit what $n$ can give rise to $\phi(n)=30$

Comment: I already know that ϕ(n) is based on the prime divisors of a given number, but I don't know how to exclude the divisors of 30 that will not be needed to calculate aϕ(n)= 30 for example (2,3,5) I don't know if I have to go there or somewhere else

Comment: [How to solve the equation $\phi(n) = k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23947) might be useful

Comment: @ManuelRodrigues If you still haven't seen the answer from the hints, reply to this comment and I will post an answer.